# How can I send user registration details from Django to a postgresql table

Tags: html, django, postgresql

I've successfully migrated my database to postgresql, but the issue is I don't know how to send user registration/login details to my postgresql table, please any help is appreciated. Or maybe a link or site where I can browse the course tutorial.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: if yo mean user management, this is an entire course not an answer! You can have a look into a project of mine  https://github.com/IT-Support-L2/Django-Todo-API

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot